# sql float zero padding

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wondering if there is a way to convert a float number in SQL to a zero padded number after the decimal point for example if I have the following table:

```
.--------------------.-------.
|        name        | grade |
.--------------------.-------.
| courseE            | 5     |
| courseG            | 4     |
| courseB            | 2.5   |
| courseC            | 2.5   |
| courseF            | 1.25  |
| courseD            | 0     |
```

I want to convert the field `grade` to a zerro padded number and the result would be like this:

```
.--------------------.-------.
|        name        | grade |
.--------------------.-------.
| courseE            | 5.000 |
| courseG            | 4.000 |
| courseB            | 2.500 |
| courseC            | 2.500 |
| courseF            | 1.250 |
| courseD            | 0.000 |
```

I have tried to convert the field grade as float by usibg the `CAST(EXP) AS FLOAT` but why it did not work with me?!

thanks in advance

Comment: This is a **presentation** issue and so should be handled by your presentation layer: report, form, application, webpage, etc.

Comment: @gvee no,I did it before by just using the CAST and it worked but now it did not work!

Comment: Just because you *can* do something in SQL, doesn't mean it *should* be done there.

Comment: I have told you it should be in SQL because I have seen that in other tables!!

Comment: What is the type of your column?

Comment: it is float divided by another float using CAST!

Comment: I agree with gvee, if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error starts at `float` - since there's no such data type available for [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) conversion. Instead you should use `DECIMAL`, which allows you also to set decimal and numeric parts:

```
SELECT name, CAST(grade AS DECIMAL(4, 3)) FROM t
```

About format: first number indicates how many **total** digits will hold your `decimal` value, while second number indicates how many **decimal** digits will be (i.e. after dot). To be more precise, it's not *format*, it's certain data-type restriction definitions (since `decimal` is a special fixed-point data type in MySQL)

Comment: what if my number does not have fixed number of digits ,this will no work!

Comment: this will work - just change `4` to `10` (or similar) - whole number will not exceed defined restriction, while it's integer part will be represented correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
select  convert(decimal(10, 3), @number)
```

The number "3" represents the number of decimals you want after the "."

Comment: if I want to convert grade in this:select tid,sid,coalesce(grade,0)as grade from teaches, what should I do?!

Comment: This is the SQL for what it sounds you want. Replace "@number" with your column.